# Using the same upload certificate for multiple apps in Google Play Console

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-app-signing

I'm using app signing by Google play for my first app. I created a new app with a new signing certificate, but I want to use the same upload certificate. Is it possible to use the same upload certificate for multiple apps in Google Play Console? If so, is this a good practice? What potential problems are there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it okay to sign two different applications with the same key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418055/is-it-okay-to-sign-two-different-applications-with-the-same-key)

Comment: @P.Mohanta Thanks, but the question you linked is about using the same signing certificate for different apps, I'm interested in using single upload certificate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible, yes.

In general, sharing keys across apps is not recommended (upload or signing), since losing/compromising one will compromise all apps sharing the same key, but because the upload key can easily be reset, it is not as big of an issue.

Make sure to use a different app signing certificate for the app though, unless the two apps need to share a process.